# How do we create the Indian Rupee (INR) symbol in gmail using html or uni code?

Tags: html, email, gmail

I have tried using unicode and HTML code but it doesn’t seem to recognise the same. I understand there is an easier way by copying the symbol in word document but I just wanted to know if there is a way using HTML or Unicode in gmail compose box programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code that generates Indian rupee symbol using unicode in html.

```
<html>
<h1>&#8377;</h1>
</html>
```

Hope it will be useful for you.

Comment: Not working, You can't type directly HTML code inside gmail composer. It is taking only text